# Cryptic error messages in OL3 v3.14.0

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, google-closure

I am getting cryptic error messages in my console with OL3 v3.14.0. I just upgraded. Here is an example:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , d.f) is not a function
```

I have javascript source maps enabled. Can someone let me know how I should have my environment configured so that I can see the actual error?

Comment: What console are you looking at? Does chrome throw the same error?

Comment: Use the debug version for error messages and stack traces

Comment: To clarify the above comment: for debugging, use `ol-debug.js` instead of `ol.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `ol-debug.js` this will give you a more informative error, and allow you to step through the library using a browser's developer tools.

When bug fixing, or developing, I usually have a commented out bit of html to pull in an `ol-debug.js` cdn as needed, and switch with `ol.js`:

```
<!--  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.14.0/ol-debug.js"></script>-->
```